# How can I make photo change once uploaded with this form

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, forms

I am trying to work around this, I know it might need mysql, php or something but i will like to know how i can make the imageuploaded.jpg in this html change anytime a new one is uploaded with the html form below? before voting the question down please give a suggestion at least. I am new to html

```
                    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Photo </legend>
        <p align="center"><img src="imageuploaded.jpg" /></p>
        </fieldset>
        </td>
<form name="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input id="browse" type="file" name="image">
<input id="upload" type="submit" name="Submit"value="upload" />
</form> 
<form name="insert" method="post">
<p>
```

Comment: mysql no, php yes. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
if ($_POST && $_FILES['image']['name']) {
  $avatar = $_FILES['image']['name'];
} else {
  $avatar = "noimage.jpg";
}
?>

<fieldset>
        <legend>User Photo </legend>
        <p align="center"><img src="<?php echo $avatar;?>" /></p>
</fieldset>
</td>
<form name="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input id="browse" type="file" name="image">
<input id="upload" type="submit" name="Submit"value="upload" />
</form>
<p>
```

Comment: i believe i will need to create a php file and an action directed to the php file, right? Pardon me if I am vague but like I said earlier I am new

Comment: it uploaded but didn't show because the photo didn't post to my directory so it just showed a broken photo. is there a way for me to get the photo to upload to a folder names "online"